# Lost funds via phishing/approval. Please help

Tags: ether, uniswap, scam, phishing

It appears that ~0.137 ETH was automatically sent from my address to "Fake_Phishing188250" via a "Claim" transaction (0xef67d184ff919c922d499b8d1a3fbabec757176e2fbf32d40bfeff7364534cc8). I did not manually sign this transaction but recently made some approvals on Uniswap (or so I thought).

Can anyone help me understand how this happened and how to secure my wallet? Thanks